# Regarding fault-tolerance for suppress operator in KTable

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

We are planning to use suppress operator over Session Windowed KTable.
We are wondering about fault-tolerance when using suppress operator.

We understand that buffer is used to store events/aggregations until the window  closes.
Now let us say a rebalance has happened, and active task is moved to different machine. We are wondering what happens to this (in-memory ?) buffer.

Let us say we are tracking click count by user. And we configured session window's in-activity period to be 3 minutes, and session window has started for a key alice, and aggregations happened for that key for 2 minutes. For example in buffer we have (alice -> 5) entry representing that alice had made 5 clicks in this session so far.

And say there is no activity after that from alice.

If things are working fine , then once the session is over, downstream processor will get event alice -> 5 .

But what if there is rebalance now, and active task that is maintaining session window for alice is moved to new machine ?
Since there is no further activity from alice, will downstream processor which is running on new machine miss this event alice ->5 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suppress operator provides fault tolerance similarly to any other state store in Streams. Although the active data structure is in memory, the suppression buffer maintains a changelog (an internal Kafka topic).

So, when you have that rebalance, the previous active task flushes its state to the changelog and discards the in-memory buffer. The new active task re-creates the state by replaying the changelog topic, resulting in the exact same buffered contents as if there had been no rebalance.

In other words, just like in-memory state stores, the suppression buffer is made durable (in a Kafka topic) even though it is not persistent (on the local disk).

Does that make sense?